# Distributed Erlang node with multiple names

Tags: erlang, distributed-system

is it possible to configure an erlang node with multiple long node names? Here are two use cases:

1. I have an erlang node running on a machine with multiple IPs say 172.16.1.2 and 172.17.1.2. Other nodes in the cluster need to be able to send message to this node via either IP address. So I need the node to have the name of x@172.16.1.2 and x@172.17.1.2.
2. I use the node in both IPC and RPC settings. Other processes in the same machine talk to this node via 127.0.0.1 (let's assume these processes are not aware of the external IP). The node also needs to talk to external world via the external IP. So it will be ideal that the node is run with x@127.0.0.1 and x@.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An **erlang node cannot have multiple names**. This is by design. For example, there can be at most one `erl_epmd` server which is responsible for registering the name to `epmd`.

Nevertheless, you can solve your use cases with **hostnames instead of IPs**. Each node will resolve the name locally. You can achieve this with your systems `/etc/hosts` file or with [inetrc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/inet_cfg.html) files.

Eventually, you might want to use short names instead of long names.